# Calculating geodesic curvature for a general curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, geodesic

A cylinder of radius $R$ can be parameterized by $X(\theta, z) = [R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta, z]$, where $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ and $\infty < z < \infty$.

Part b of the question I'm working on (studying for an exam) asks me to calculate the geodesic curvature for a general curve - I am stuck on this.

Part a asks to find the metric and the normal to the surface, so I assume those quantities are useful in the part I am stuck on.

If anyone could give me guidance on how to calculate geodesic curvature for a general curve on the above surface, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the cylinder $C$ consider the curve
$\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, h(t))$, where $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is some smooth function.

the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ is 
$$κ_g=\dfrac{h''(t)}{(1+h'(t)^2)^{3/2}}$$

The geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ vanishes if and only if $h(t)=at+b$ for certain constants a and b (line a plane).

Use the isometry between the cylinder and plane to argue that the geodesic curvature of the curve $\gamma$ on the cylinder must be the same as that of the graph of $u= h(v)$ in the plane.

Comment: @ Srey Look for the Liouviles's formula..using the first fundamental form.